# Splash screen with progress bar Windows Phone not displaying

Tags: windows-phone-8, splash-screen

I have create a usercontrol for a splash screen to display when my app starts see code below. But the problem is that the text and prograss bar I want display on top of it doesn't display. I can't figure out what I've done wrong here? It's probablly something simple!

code:

```
 <UserControl 
x:Class="ContosoSocial.SplashScreenPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">





<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Image Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Source="SplashScreenImage.jpg"></Image>


    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             TextAlignment="Center" 
             Height="60" 
             Margin="14,630,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="App &amp; Database..."
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="456" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" 
             FontSize="16" 
             BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
             Background="{x:Null}" 
             Foreground="White" 
             SelectionBackground="{x:Null}" 
             SelectionForeground="{x:Null}"/>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Height="10"
                 Margin="10,680,0,0" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="460" 
                 IsIndeterminate="True" 
                 Foreground="White"/>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="10"
                 Margin="10,695,0,0" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="460" 
                 FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                 Foreground="White" 
                 IsIndeterminate="True"/>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

</Grid>
```

The control run fine in Visual Studio window, I can see the text and progress bars running on top on the splash screen image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly. Just add

```
Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"
```

in your LayoutRoot Grid since you text seems to be white in color. You can refer the [source code](http://1drv.ms/1zVRLXD) which I tried.